# Отсутствует перевод о том как надо создавать таблицы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, markdown, таблицы

Отсутствует перевод `Tables` и его содержимого

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Утвердил предложенные [MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512) переводы с небольшими правками и добавил некоторые новые:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15638
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15673
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15636
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15641
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15674
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15643
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15681
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15669
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15635

Будет на сайте в свежих сборках. Текущая 2020.12.18.38240